# I make top of Articles ? but when i start my project i had error unhashable type: 'slice'

Tags: python, html, django

I make a list of articles that will be filtered by submission, I want regular articles in me, and then the most popular articles go to articles.
I do everything vrodiby and I want to display them with I made a function that will filter the articles and then I output them using

```
    {% for top in articles_top %}

    <h1> {{ top.title }} </h1>

    {%  endfor %}
```

And I just need a function and not a class like this

```
class ArticleIndex(ListView):
    model = Articles
    queryset = Articles.objects.all().order_by('-view')
    template_name = 'news/posts.html'
    paginate_by = 6
```

my Traceback:

```
File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  157.         context = self.get_context_data()

File "D:\Users\MAestro\Desktop\RapterGame.com\itRapter\news\views.py" in get_context_data
  34.         context = super(ArticleIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in get_context_data
  119.             paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in paginate_queryset
  69.             page = paginator.page(page_number)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py" in page
  75.         return self._get_page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)

Exception Type: TypeError at /news/
Exception Value: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

views.py

```
class ArticleIndex(ListView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'news/posts.html'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        articles_top = Articles.objects.order_by('-view')
        context_top={'articles_top':articles_top}
        return context_top
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`get_queryset`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) is *not* supposed to return a dictionary or something else than a queryset. If you want to give the object a different name in the template, you should specify the [**`context_object_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.context_object_name) attribute.

If you want to add extra attributes, you can override the [**`get_context_data`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data) and add extra attributes. Note that these will not be paginates (unless you paginate these explicitly).

```
class ArticleIndex(ListView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'news/posts.html'
    paginate_by = 6
    queryset = Articles.objects.order_by('-view')
    context_object_name = 'articles_top'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(articles=Articles.objects.all())
        return context
```

Comment: I did not want to give a name to the object, I want to have two objects, one sorts by views and the other is not, and both should be displayed in the template

Comment: @NeIT: then you should add the other one to the context.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class ArticleIndex(ListView):
         template_name = 'ap_blog/categoria.html'
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ArticleIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['Articles'] = Articles.objects.all()
            context['articles_top'] = Programs.objects.all()
            return context
```